# MAUI and MauiMTAdmob: Google Play rejected my app because families ad format requirements

Tags: android, maui, google-play-console

I have created an app using `NET8` `MAUI`. In this app, I'm using [MauiMTAdmob](https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob) to display the advertisements from *Google AdMob*. In particular, there is at the bottom of the main page and in other pages a banner and there are some interstitial advertisements during the normal use of the app.

When I pushed the app to the Google Play, Google rejected the app because

> Issue found: Families ad format requirements
>
> Your app contains ads that don’t comply with our Families ad format requirements. For example, we don’t allow:
>
> - Ads or offers for in-app purchases that aren’t clearly distinguishable from your app content, including but not limited to offerwalls and immersive ads experiences. For example, your app contains an ad that isn’t clearly labeled, or your app contains an ad that’s stylistically similar to the game interface.

As an action, Google suggests to

- To resolve this issue, remove any violating ad content before submitting an app update.
- Make sure your app uses a version of the [Families Self-Certified Ads SDKs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12955712?visit_id=638403870057518181-1266363707&rd=1) listed in the program. For details, refer to the “Format requirements” section of the [Families Ads and Monetization](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9893335#ads_and_monetization) policy.

I checked *Google AdMob* but I can't find any certificate to add to the app. Also, in the documentation, there is a reference to an [Android 20.6.0 GMA SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/sdk) or later and/or [iOS GMA SDK 7.67.0](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download). I don't know how to use them with `MAUI`.

What can I do to fix this issue?